# How to add HTTP lifecycle middleware handler to spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a **CustomerController.java**:

```
package com.satisfeet.http;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.satisfeet.core.model.Address;
import com.satisfeet.core.model.Customer;
import com.satisfeet.core.service.CustomerService;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService service;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Customer> index() {
        return this.service.list();
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Customer create(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        this.service.create(customer);

        return customer;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{id}")
    public Customer show(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return this.service.show(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.PUT, value = "/{id}")
    public void update(@PathVariable Integer id, @RequestBody Customer customer) {
        this.service.update(id, customer);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.DELETE, value = "/{id}")
    public void destroy(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        this.service.delete(id);
    }

}
```

and a **ExceptionController.java**:

```
package com.satisfeet.http;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

import com.satisfeet.core.exception.NotFoundException;

@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity notFoundError() {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

I would now like to add some sort of HTTP request-response middleware which is executed before the response is written and write the HTTP status code in json:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 OK
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json

{"error":"not found"}
```

I know how to convert a `HttpStatus` to a `String` but I do not know where I could do this globally with `@ControllerAdvice`.

**So how do I register a global handler which has access to a response object?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

i think what you are looking for is spring  `Interceptor` .

please check this [tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/2676/spring-mvc-interceptors-example-handlerinterceptor-and-handlerinterceptoradapter) which is describing how to use interceptors .

and check spring documentation [Intercepting requests with a HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) .

finally check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292549/957654)

Hope that helps .

Comment: The tutorial link is dead btw. use https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/spring-mvc-interceptor-example-handlerinterceptor-handlerinterceptoradapter instead. However, the contents of the linked tutorial should not be used, as the HandlerInterceptorAdaptor is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

To whom ever this may concern regarding the answer, the class `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is now deprecated. You can implement the `HandlerInterceptor` which comes in the form of an interface instead. You can then implement `preHandle`, `postHandle`, or `afterCompletion` methods. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136917/spring-boot-2-4-0-the-type-handlerinterceptoradapter-is-deprecated) question.