# Spring boot 2.4.0 The type HandlerInterceptorAdapter is deprecated

Tags: spring, spring-boot

After upgrade Spring boot version: 2.1.3.RELEASE -> 2.4.0

I got a warning:

```
The type HandlerInterceptorAdapter is deprecated
```

Are there any replacements?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

As of Spring 5.3 in favor of implementing HandlerInterceptor and/or AsyncHandlerInterceptor directly.

[Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html)

So,

```
extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter -> implements HandlerInterceptor
```

Comment: the link is dead, I'm upgrading from srpring-boot 2.1.2 to 3.0.1 and bumping into issues importing org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter

Answer (score 1):

However, Java 8 added the concept of default methods in interfaces. Naturally, the Spring team updated the framework to make full use of the new Java language features. Since Spring 5 with Java 8 baseline allows default methods, the adapter class `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` is no longer required. Now All the methods defined inside `HandlerInterceptor` are default methods- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.9/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Use instead

```
public class CustomHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor{
  // override default methods
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Earlier -
HandlerInterceptor and HandlerInterceptorAdapter
In the first one we need to override all three methods: preHandle(), postHandle() and afterCompletion(),
In the second we may implement only required methods.

Now in latest version , we can implement directly handlerInterceptor no need of adaptor
we may implement only required methods.